# Nuxt - Fonts are not preloaded in <head> despite configuring in nuxt.config.js

Tags: nuxt.js

I created and deployed a Nuxt project, and Google Pagespeed points out (rightfully) that my fonts are not preloaded when displaying the page, which hurts my PageSpeed score a lot.

I already checked this question: [nuxt.js - preload .woff fonts loaded as @font-face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54083703/nuxt-js-preload-woff-fonts-loaded-as-font-face) and also this issue: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1508, but I could not fix the problem. Here is what I tried...

Currently my fonts are loaded in `assets/scss/_text.scss`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Raleway-Medium;
  src: url("~assets/fonts/Raleway/Raleway-Medium.woff2");
}
// ...
```

Then in `assets/scss/main.scss`:

```
@import '~assets/scss/_text.scss';
// ...
```

And finally in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
export default {
  // ...
  css: ['@/assets/scss/main.scss'],
  // ...
  render: {
    bundleRenderer: {
      shouldPreload: (_file, type) => {
        console.log(_file, type)
        return ['script', 'style', 'font'].includes(type)
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Unfortunately, my fonts are not preloaded at all. Actually, the `console.log` I added in the `bundleRenderer` function does not even find any font or style file, here is what is logged:

```
runtime.js script                                                                 
commons.app.js script                                                             
vendors.app.js script                                                             
app.js script
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody is having the same problem: font preloading is only active in **universal mode**, and **does not activate in dev mode**.

Changing to universal mode and running `npm run generate` creates pages in `dist/` with the fonts preloaded.

Comment: I have the same issue but I get a lot of errors if I try to generate from the universal mode because I use the var window in the wrong place... I'm still looking for a solution to make it work from the "spa" mode, I'll come back here if I find one

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I'm using a workaround, but I'm pretty sure it's not a perfect solution.

I wrote a node script (post-build.js) that I run after the "generate" command.

I use [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) to modifiy html file content

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const links = []

fs.readdirSync('./dist/_nuxt/fonts/').forEach((file) => {
  const fileExtension = file.split('.')[1]
  if (fileExtension === 'woff2') {
    links.push(
      `<link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/fonts/${file}" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>`
    )
  }
})

const html = fs.readFileSync('./dist/index.html', 'utf8')
const $ = cheerio.load(html)
$('head').append(links.join(' '))

fs.writeFileSync(`./dist/index.html`, $.html(), 'utf8', () => {})
```

So then i add following lin in my scripts of my package.json file

```
"scripts:{
   "generate": "nuxt generate && node ./npm-scripts/post-build.js"
}
```